# Is it possible to write the JMS Reciever with out a count down

Tags: jms

I'm new to JMS. Please correct me if my question does not make sense.
Im writing a program which use jms to send objects. But in my program the number of objects that I send time to time is varying. So I can not use count down in receiver side. And also I was unable to find the way to know the JMS queue length though I searched a lot.
So please guide me to a way that How can I read my queue till all the objects are consumed.

below is my code, And it reads only the first object of the queue

```
public class QReciever{

private static QueueConnection qConn;
private static QueueSession qSession;
private static Queue que;

private static BuildInfo recieveBuildInfo;


///INner Class

public static class ExListener implements MessageListener{
    public void onMessage(Message msg){
        System.out.println("IN side onMessage method in Inner class");
        try {
            ObjectMessage objMsg = (ObjectMessage) msg;
            setRecieveBuildInfo((BuildInfo)objMsg.getObject());
            System.out.println("############################ Inside the Inner class\n\t Build No is: "+getRecieveBuildInfo().getBuildNo());
            write2Db(getRecieveBuildInfo());

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



public static BuildInfo getRecieveBuildInfo() {
    return recieveBuildInfo;
}
public static void setRecieveBuildInfo(BuildInfo recieveBuildInfo) {
    QReciever.recieveBuildInfo = recieveBuildInfo;
}



public static void recieveQueue() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("############################Inside recieveQueue");  //####################################################################

//Jndi lookup   
    Properties props = ProptManager.getProperties();

    InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext(props);
    Object temp = initCtx.lookup("XAConnectionFactory");
    QueueConnectionFactory qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory) temp;
    qConn = qcf.createQueueConnection();
    qConn.start();
    que = (Queue) initCtx.lookup("queue/MyQueue");
    qSession = qConn.createQueueSession(false, qSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    QueueReceiver qReciever = qSession.createReceiver(que);

    qReciever.setMessageListener(new ExListener());



    qReciever.close();
    System.out.println("qReciever Closed");
    qSession.close();
    System.out.println("qSession Closed");
    qConn.close();
    System.out.println("qConn Closed");
    //System.exit(1);
}

public static void write2Db(BuildInfo bInfo){
    System.out.println("############################  Inside write2Db ");
                 //writing to the database
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: Updating Database, The record which the Build No is: "+bInfo.getBuildNo()+" may already inserted" + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Comment: I replaced the QueueReciever part with
{
MessageConsumer consumer = qSession.createConsumer(que);
consumer.setMessageListener(new ExListener());

Now It consumes the message but I am still unable to directly know whether all the queue elements are consumed or not???
plz someone guide me
}

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no direct method to do this. But there are 2 (maybe more..) ways to do this. Although I think most of them are rather inefficient/slow/...

If I understand you correctly, you send in batches ie you send data every day or hour for a short period. My 'solution' does not work if you send continuously.

What you could do, depending on your JMS implementation (if you're willing to do something specific): You could use JMX (if your JMS provider offers it, SonicMQ does, for example) to find out if there are any other messages in the queue.

Or you could create a seperate QueueBrowser, to peek and see if there are any other messages.

Maybe you can add some more info about your use case, so we know why you need to know if there are more messages in that queue.

I think the QueueBrowser is the easiest thing to do, but I think it's neither elegant nor efficient, you might want to find a different solution.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to add another protocol over the JMS queues you are using.

If you have a single producer and a single consumer you can have the producer send a header message first containing the total number of messages about to be sent and a trailer message last signaling no more messages.  This would allow you to display a count and detect any missing messages.

But I don't think this is a good use of queues.  With a queue you generally want each message to be independent.  It should not matter to the consumer how many messages have arrived it just handles a single message as blindly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply set a boolean property on the last message to indicate you're done.